# Can't seem to get generate-id working in XSLT

Tags: xml, transform, xslt

In a `for-each` statement, I want to generate IDs for every matched node.

Given some XML file:

```
<event attr1="qwertz">
  <test>Test</test>
</event>
<event attr1="asdfg">
  <test>Test</test>
</event>
```

... and the following rule:

```
<xsl:for-each select="event">
  <xsl:element name="event">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">id/{generate-id(test)}</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I always get something like this:

```
<event id="id/generate-id(test)"/>
<event id="id/generate-id(test)"/>
<event id="id/generate-id(test)"/>
...
```

What is the correct syntax for calling this function in XSLT? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<event id="id/{generate-id(test)}"/>
```

Or the verbose:

```
<xsl:element name="event">
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:text>id/<xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="generate-id(test)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

**Note**: Attribute Value Templates are only for literal result elements and only some attributes of XSLT instructions.